# How to remove from QuerySet by some condition

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a queryset, and lets say its described like this (in JSON)

```
{
  [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "01_correct_answers": 1,
      "02_correct_answers": 3,
    }, 
    {
      "name": "John",
      "01_correct_answers": null,
      "02_correct_answers": null,
    },
    {
      "name": "James",
      "01_correct_answers": null,
      "02_correct_answers": 3,
    },
  ]
}
```

Here `01` and `02` are subject IDs. And I have a list of these IDs, now how can I loop through this list of IDs and check the queryset if the `correct_answers` of the student for these subjects are not null, if they are null (all subjects), just remove them from the queryset.
And finally I would like to have a filtered queryset like below:

```
{
  [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "01_correct_answers": 1,
      "02_correct_answers": 3,
    }, 
    {
      "name": "James",
      "01_correct_answers": null,
      "02_correct_answers": 3,
    },
  ]
}
```

I would like to do something like this

```
subjects = ['01', '02']
new_queryset = q.exclude(
  # for subject in subjects: f"{subject}_correct_answers"=None
)
```

Comment: It does not seem as a correct JSON. Share also the code you are taking this JSON from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query with:

```
subjects = ['01', '02']

new_queryset = q.exclude(
    Q(*[(f'{sub}_correct_answers', None) for sub in subjects])
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working, but what is the asterisk doing in this query?

Comment: @mecdeality Yes that's what I am not understanding either.

Comment: @mecdeality: if you call a function `f(*[1,4,2,5])` that is equivalent to calling it like `f(1,4,2,5)`. We here thus construct a `Q` with `Q(('01_correct_answers', None), ('02_correct_answers', None))` for example.

Comment: @SunderamDubey: see above comment.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How can I exclude both 0 and ``None``s ? (lets say if the ``correct_answers`` is 0 as well)

Comment: Perhaps: `new_queryset = q.exclude(
    Q(*[item for sub in subjects for item in ((f'{sub}_correct_answers', None), (f'{sub}_correct_answers', 0)))])`